# Fantasy TV anime or Western cartoon series with a medieval type setting mid 1980s

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

The only thing I remember about this show was the end credit sequence had a parade where a female jester does acrobatics while people are throwing confetti and such.
I think the jester was wearing skintight clothing, I think she had blonde hair also, maybe wearing one of those funny jester hats with 3 tails?

I remember renting this particular show in the UK but I don't think it was British.

Comment: This is a bit spare on details. Was there magic? Monsters? Was the female jester dressed in a skintight suit? Colors of the outfit? Mask? Did the acrobatics look realistic or were there routine standing double or triple flips?

Comment: What makes this a fantasy?  Spells?  Wizards?  Magic gems?  Elves?  Witches?  Talking swords?

Comment: Were there any other acts in this parade except the jester? Was she a character in the actual show or just the credits?

Comment: There was an episode of Galaxy Rangers that was in a Mideval world.